# Solve $4\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int_0^b5x^2dxdydz$

Tags: definite-integrals, greens-theorem

I tried solving this problem:

Evaluate $\iint_Sx^3dydz+x^2ydzdx+x^2zdxdy$

Where S is the surface bounded by $z=0, z=b, x^2+y^2=a^2$

Using Green Theorem,
$\iint_Sx^3dydz+x^2ydzdx+x^2zdxdy=\iiint_V\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial z}=\iiint_V5x^2dxdydz$

Inserting the intervals gives: $4\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int_0^b5x^2dxdydz$

I multiplied the integral by 4 since there are four quadrants.

The problem is now to calculate $4\int_0^a\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int_0^b5x^2dxdydz$

I got $10a^4b\pi$

However the textbook I'm studying gave a contrary answer: $\frac{5}{4}\pi a^4b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to evaluate the integral in cylindrical coordinates.  We have

$$\int_0^b \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a 5\rho^2\cos^2\phi \rho \,d\rho\, d\phi\, dz=5\pi b\frac{a^4}{4} \tag 1$$

where we used $\cos^2\phi =\frac{1+\cos 2\phi}{2}$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos 2\phi d\phi=0$ to evaluate the integral in $(1)$

In Cartesian coordinates, we can evaluate the volume integral as

$$\begin{align}
4\int_0^b \int_0^a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}5x^2dx\,dy\,dz&=20b\int_0^a\,\frac13  (a^2-y^2)^{3/2}\\\\
&=20b\frac13 \left(\frac{3\pi a^4}{16}\right)\\\\
&=\frac54 \pi a^4b
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: It is all about the geometry; nice answer!

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks!  I edited to add the integral in Cartesian coordinates, which is much more difficult.